# When is the order important in Combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics

**In a shop five different type of chocolates are sold.**

**How many different ways 6 chocolate bars can be chosen in such a way that at least 3 chocolate bars must be of type one and at most one of type two?**

I'm trying to figure it out if order is important and repetition is allowed in the question and how is it possible to know if order is important in such questions because I only know that its important if we can choose same type in the same time but i couldn't figure it out in this difficult question

Comment: I'd say that the type of chocolate bar is distinguished, but the order of purchase is not.  So, for instance, if we call the types A, B, C, D, and E, then AAABCD is the same as DBACAA is the same as ABACAD.  Those count as only one way to buy six chocolate bars.

Comment: i can understand now that order is not important

Comment: and i think logically i understood it but still how can i solve it using combination formula because its still hard to put it in a formula

Comment: The question about order is completely relative, it depends on how you interpret the question. From some common point of view some kind of problem are seeing as "unordered" relative to some other problems. Just forget completely the question about order and just calculate.

Comment: i am trying to calculate it but i didn't find a way to calculate type 1 into a combination formula its confusing me

Comment: In this problem, what matters is the number of each type of chocolate bar that are sold.

Comment: This is an English question, not a math question.  When a problem is posed, the poser should make it clear.  Unfortunately, sometimes it is not.  Clearly repetition is allowed here as there are not enough types of bar not to repeat.  I would say order does not matter here because I imagine leaving the shop with a bag of six bars and not caring what order they were placed in the bag.  I don't think it is certain that is correct.

Comment: now its more clear to me but i'm studing Combinatorics and always i've to solve the questions using combinations or permutation formula and i know that i've to use combination with repetition but my problem is how to put type 1 in the formula

Comment: If $x_k$ is the number of chocolate bars of type $k$ that are sold, you need to find the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 6$  subject to the restrictions that $x_1 \geq 3$ and that $x_2 \leq 1$.

Comment: So, 5C3+5C4+5C5+5C0+5C1 right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming as Brian Tung indicates, the order of purchase does not matter, consider the first 3 bars to be of Type 1. This is fixed, so it doesn't affect the count. So we have 3 more bars to choose.

Now we have two choices: do we include a bar of Type 2, or not?

- If we include a type 2 bar, then there are 2 more bars to choose, which can be any type other than 2. (Note that since the requirement on type 1 bar is *at least 3*, the remaining bars can be type 1 as well.)
- If we do not include a type 2 bar, then there are 3 more bars to choose, which can be any type other than 2.

Can you figure it out from that?

Comment: So, 5C3+5C4+5C5+5C0+5C1 right?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and $E$ be the different types of chocolates, so the order is not important.

First, we can choose $6$ bars all in type $A$ or $B$ or $C$ or $D$ or $E$ ($5$ outcomes).

- Or, we can choose $5$ in type $A$, and $1$ from the ($B$, $C$, $D$ or $E$) $= \binom{4}{1}$.
- Or, $5$ in type $B$, and $1$ from the ($A$, $C$, $D$ or $E$) $= \binom{4}{1}$.
- Or, $5$ in type $C$, and $1$ from the ($A$, $B$, $D$ or $E$) $= \binom{4}{1}$.
- Or, $5$ in type $D$, and $1$ from the ($A$, $C$, $B$ or $E$) $= \binom{4}{1}$.
- Or, $5$ in type $E$, and $1$ from the ($A$, $C$, $D$ or $B$) $= \binom{4}{1}$.

So, that means $5$ times $\binom{4}{1}$.

Or, we can choose $4$ in type $A$, and $2$ from the ($B$, $C$, $D$ or $E$) $= \binom{4}{2}$.

Or, $4$ in type $B$, and $2$ from the ($A$, $C$, $D$ or $E$) $= \binom{4}{2}$.

Or, $4$ in type $C$, and $2$ from the ($A$, $B$, $D$ or $E$) $= \binom{4}{2}$.

Or, $4$ in type $D$, and $2$ from the ($A$, $C$, $B$ or $E$) $= \binom{4}{2}$.

Or, $4$ in type $E$, and $2$ from the ($A$, $C$, $D$ or $B$) $= \binom{4}{2}$.

That means $5$ times $\binom{4}{2}$.

Or Finally, we can choose $3$ in type $A$, and $3$ from the ($B$, $C$, $D$ or $E$) $= \binom{4}{3}$.

Or, $3$ in type $B$, and $3$ from the ($A$, $C$, $D$ or $E$) $= \binom{4}{3}$.

Or, $3$ in type $C$, and $3$ from the ($A$, $B$, $D$ or $E$) $= \binom{4}{3}$.

Or, $3$ in type $D$, and $3$ from the ($A$, $C$, $B$ or $E$) $= \binom{4}{3}$.

Or, $3$ in type $E$, and $3$ from the ($A$, $C$, $D$ or $B$) $= \binom{4}{3}$.

So it's going to be $5$ times $\binom{4}{3}$.

By adding all the outcomes we will have $5\left(1+\binom{4}{1}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{4}{3}\right)= 75$ different ways.